# Kubernetes capability to write to /proc/sys/* files

Tags: linux, kubernetes

We have a container in a pod that runs with privileged mode (i.e. has `spec.containers[].securityContext.privilege = true`). We are moving it from privileged mode to use more tailored capabilities. One of the things it does, though, is to enable IP forwarding by editing `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`:

```
echo 1 >|/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Now that the pod is not privileged anymore, it fails with this message:

```
/usr/local/bin/start.sh: line 20: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Read-only file system
```

Is there some specific capability that would allow us to write to `/proc/sys/*` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unprivileged containers mount [/proc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/ch-proc) read-only, which prevents them from enabling `net.ipv4.ip\_forward` in their own network namespace. This GitHub [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62942) provides a workaround for this limitation.

Any configuration changes made using the **echo** command disappear when the system is restarted. To ensure that the configuration changes take effect after a system reboot, use `sysctl` commands. Refer to the [document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-proc-sysctl) for using the sysctl command to modify the parameters of ip_forward.

If you need to change parameters in `/proc/sys`, the best thing to do is edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and then run `sysctl -p`. This ensures that your changes will persist across reboots.